# Powershell invoke-webrequest downloading HTML not actual file

Tags: powershell, google-sheets

I am trying to download a google spreadsheet via an `invoke-webrequest`in powershell.

My link looks something like this and I can confirm that if I go to the link it prompts me to download the file I want...

`$url = https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/export?format=csv`

I have tried downloading the file via 2 ways:

`Invoke-WebRequest $url -OutFile $saveLocation`

`(New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile($url, $saveLocation)`

Both of these just download the HTML for the page, and not the actual file.

The spreadsheet I am downloading is 100% public so it is not like I need to be logged into a google account to view it.

Comment: works perfectly for me. Can you share the link to csv you are trying to export?

Comment: I assume `$csvUrl` should be `$url`?

Comment: @Harsh I have the same issue as OP

Comment: Can you please post your sample url, @sodawillow

Comment: @Harsh : see my answer

Comment: @sodawillow I was able to successfully download your file using WebClient.DownloadFile

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made the test and I can quite safely say that your file is not public.

I have reproduced your issue before making my test sheet public, and I could not afterwards.

Tested with this :

```
$url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1OOc5aiG3hh8mrGF4p7NJXKI8KqBSkS2ZjsBXtb4qpz8/export?format=csv"

Invoke-WebRequest $url -OutFile "C:\test.csv"
```